# Extract String parts and add to ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist, split, substring

I have a problem with String substring option.
I wanted to add some parts from a String into an ArrayList, but I only get to add the first text.

```java
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
String text = "[\"text1\",\"text2\",\"text3\"]";

   text = text.substring(text.indexOf("\"") + 1);
   text = text.substring(0, text.indexOf("\""));

   arr.add(text);


   for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(arr.get(i));
   }
```

The output for this is:

```
text1
```

I would like the add all "texts" in the Array, each one in a different position:

```
text1
text2
text3
```

Is there any possibility to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to manually parse JSON arrays of strings? You should use a JSON parser to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `split` fairly easily:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String input = "[\"text1\",\"text2\",\"text3\"]";
    final List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for(final String item : input.replaceAll("^\\[\"|\"\\]$", "").split("\",\"")) {
        output.add(item);
    }
    for(final String item : output) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
text1
text2
text3
```

The `String` you are trying to parse looks amazingly like the output of `Collection.toString`, if that's the case then this is all wrong...

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
    String text = "[\"text1\",\"text2\",\"text3\"]";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
"text1"
"text2"
"text3"
```

Answer (score 1):

[**`String#split`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)  using the regex and don't add the first and last element in the array to the arraylist.

```
String str[]=text.split("\"(,)?");
ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=1;i<str.length-1;i++){
 System.out.print(str[i]+"\n");
    arr.add(str[i]);

                }
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
text1
text2
text3
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a regex pattern?:

```
String text = "[\"text1\",\"text2\",\"text3\"]";
String[] split = text.split("\"(,)?");
```